# Why this button has a small functionality area?

Tags: c#, wpf, border

I have this which is behaving like a button in a WPF Application. It has an image on it. It's working fine, however the user needs to press exactly in the middle to get its functionality.

So the image is covering the whole "button" which technically is a border. Yet users only have a very tiny space to click. All edges up to maybe 20 pixels away from each edge are not functional. **What would be the reason the user has very small functional space?**

```
<Border x:Name="previewButton" Margin="0,10" Height="89" Padding="0" MouseDown="previewButton_MouseDown" MouseUp="previewButton_MouseUp" BorderBrush="#FF535151" BorderThickness="1" MouseLeave="previewButton_MouseLeave" TouchDown="previewButton_TouchDown" TouchUp="previewButton_TouchUp" TouchLeave="previewButton_TouchLeave" >
    <Image Width="50" Source="/EZ3D;component/Resources/old/eye.png" Margin="4.2,0.2,3.4,0.2" />
</Border>
```

**Border:**

[image]

**Image on the border:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Background` of the Border to `Transparent` to make it hit-test visible:

```
<Border Background="Transparent" ...>
```

Comment: Nice and easy. Thanks :)